# Where is the random MAC address generated for tap interfaces?

Tags: c, linux

When I create a `tap` interface in Linux with `ip tuntap add mode tap` or `tunctl` commands, then it seems to get a random MAC address. For example:

```
root@fw-test:~# tunctl 
Set 'tap5' persistent and owned by uid 0
root@fw-test:~# ip link show dev tap5
11: tap5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 500
    link/ether 76:df:78:5e:d6:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root@fw-test:~#
```

If I look the *tunctl.c* source-file, then I quite don't understand where this MAC address is generated. Where and based on which rules the random MAC address is generated for tap interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `eth_random_addr` declared in the kernel header `Linux/include/linux/etherdevice.h`